# python compare datatime.time to datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a time hour, minute, seconde

```
 serverTime = 'Jul 2, 2018 3:21:56 PM'
 serverTime = serverTime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
 serverTime = datetime.strptime(serverTime, '%H:%M:%S').time()
 print(serverTime)
 >> 15:21:56
 print(type(serverTime))
 >> <class 'datetime.time'>
```

and I have a timedelta like this

```
openTimeFrom = timedelta(milliseconds=hours['fromT'] 
print(serverTime)
>> 08:00:00
print(type(openTimeFrom))
>> <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

and i want compare `openTimeFrom` and `serverTime` to know if `serverTime` is greater than `openTimeFrom` but when i do this

```
if serverTime > openTimeFrom:
```

I have this error

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. Is 7pm more or less than three minutes? You need to answer the question: three minutes *from what*? Then you can convert to a single type where a comparison has meaning.

Comment: `timedelta` is a period. So you can't compare a period with a datetime

Comment: I upvoted @jonsharpe's comment but wanted to also point out your example isn't valid. You are invoking the `strftime()` method on a string which is not valid. But even allowing for that mistake you are trying to compare an absolute date/time to a relative date time. That makes no sense.